# How to move custom template form Joomla 1.5 to 2.5?

Tags: joomla

I am migrating form Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 version. I need to move template.
I installed it with Extension Manager. It displayed in `Template Manager`. But when I am assigning this template to site- the site respond with `HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.` This template worked fine on Joomla 1.5.

Comment: Is this template compatible with Joomla 2.5? You need to ask from its developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template need a Joomla 2.5 (or 1.7) compatibility!

Comment: and how could you convert a 1.5 template into a 2.5 compatible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same inconvenient at this time, so i want to publish here my answer to help anyone who has to do this task to convert templates 1.7 to 2.5, the instructions can be found in [docs.joomla.org](http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_a_Joomla_1.5_template_to_Joomla_2.5), specifically in the section "Alternate Method Using a Version 2.5 Template".

I've tried different tools to convert them automatically without success, this method really helped me.